# Does "Max 1 per conflict" mean per player, or in total?

Tags: legend-of-the-five-rings

Some neutral cards have the text "Max one per conflict" on them. Does this mean that a player is only allowed to play one per conflict, or does it mean only one of the players is allowed to play this?

For example, Court Games has this. If my opponent plays Court Games, am I allowed to play my own Court Games later during that conflict or do I need to wait for a new conflict to happen?

Answer (score 2):

As per the [Rules Reference, page 10](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/b3/b7/b3b74cee-5ea1-44f7-a459-466c3d7edc81/l5c01-rules_reference-v101.pdf) (which is much more detailed than the rules delivered with the box):

> All limits are player specific.

Which means that yes, if my opponent plays Court Games, so can I during the same conflict.